# Stripe Checkout part 2.0

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I just wanna integrate to my website Stripe Checkout with Dynamic Data from Firebase Admin. When I cliked button, i got error like this:

```
IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
```

Page **Checkout.vue** where placed and function **pay()**:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    Total price : {{ this.$store.getters.totalPrice   }}
                </p>
                <button class='pay-with-stripe btn btn-primary mt-4' @click='pay'>Checkout</button>
            </div>
```

In methods I have function like this which is store in item productId and productQuantity.
Also here function **redirectToCheckout()**

```
pay(){
          let data = this.$store.state.card.map(item => ({ [item.productId] : item.productQuantity}));

          data = Object.assign({}, ...data);
          axios.get('https://us-central1-vue-shop-1ab39.cloudfunctions.net/CheckoutSession', {
              params: {
                  products : data
              }
          })
            .then(response => {
                this.sessionId = response.data
                console.log(response.data);
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({

                    sessionId: this.sessionId.id

                }).then(function (result) {
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
      }
  },
```

Here in file **index.js** I push products into "results" array to implement in line_items

```
const results = []

all.forEach(item => {
        const data = {};
        data.price = parseInt(item.data().price) ;
        data.currency = "kzt";
        data.description = item.data().description ;
        data.name = item.data().name;
        myProducts.forEach(q => {
            if(item.id == q[0]){
              data.quantity = q[1];
            }
        });
        results.push(data)
    });
```

Here checkout sessions

```
 stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            success_url: "https://example.com/success",
            cancel_url: "https://example.com/cancel",
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            line_items: 
                 results,
            mode: 'payment',
          }, function(err, session) {
                response.send(session);
          });
      });
```

Comment: what does ` console.log(response.data);` print?

Comment: before assigning the variable this is show me data in console

Comment: not sure what you mean. What was the value that it prints?

Comment: In tutorial says: " before assigning the variable this is show me data in console". But in my case it shows nothing. i deleted this line of code. Nothing changed. the error remained the same

Comment: I changed code and it shows this kind of value it printed: `{…}
after_expiration
: 
(...)
allow_promotion_codes
: 
(...)
amount_subtotal
: 
(...)
amount_total
: 
(...)
automatic_tax
: 
(...)
billing_address_collection
: 
(...)
cancel_url
: 
(...)`

Comment: What tutorial are you using exactly?

Comment: Try doing `this.sessionId = response.data.id` and using `console.log(this.sessionId)` too and see if that helps at all.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjKq3A0rR2A&list=PLB4AdipoHpxYPjGo0n2m6tmCLud_iSEbv&index=73) and [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6SNmMCdPhg&list=PLB4AdipoHpxYPjGo0n2m6tmCLud_iSEbv&index=77) Here tutorials

Answer (score 0):

As I assumed trouble was in line_items. I pushed in data uncorrectly. Then I checked the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment). Add line **price data** and **product_data** in forEach item. And that's it. Thank u for ur attention. Also, big thanks to user: karllekko

```
 all.forEach(item => {
        const data = {
            price_data: {
                product_data:{

                }
            }
        };
        data.price_data.unit_amount = parseFloat(item.data().price * 100);
        data.price_data.currency = "aud";
        data.price_data.product_data.name = item.data().name;

        myProducts.forEach(q => {
            if(item.id == q[0]){
              data.quantity = q[1];
            }
        });

        results.push(data)
    });
```